# PHP's PDO Source Code

Tags: php, pdo

I've got PHP installed from the repos on my Ubuntu 9.10 local machine. Where can I find the source code to the PDO classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of PHP 5.1, PDO is part of the PHP core so it should be somewhere in [there](http://www.php.net/downloads.php). My educated guess is

`/ext/pdo`

Before 5.1, it used to be a PECL package that is still available [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO). If you want to browse the source just for curiosity, it might do. If you need the current one, look in the core.

Answer (score 8):

The PHP code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/php/php-src

And the PDO classes are under [`/ext/pdo`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/pdo) as [Pekka 웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) pointed out.

In this way you don't need to download the full code, but *read it online*.

Answer (score 1):

The PDO version of pgsql should come with the php5-pgsql package.

`apt-get source php5-pgsql` will grab the source code used by the Ubuntu team to package the module for the repository.

In the source directory you're looking for something like `php5-5.2.12.dfsg.1/ext/pdo_pgsql/` the precise path will of course vary depending on the version of php used.